# How to get Samsung stylus button event from onTouch?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I am not getting a stylus button event from the Samsung S-Pen in my onTouch listener. Everything is working fine for onHover.

```
hoverListener = new View.OnHoverListener() {    
    public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i("TEST", "tooltype = " + event.getToolType(0) + ", button = " + event.getButtonState());
        return false;
      }
    };

touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {    
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i("TEST", "tooltype = " + event.getToolType(0) + ", button = " + event.getButtonState());
        return false;
      }
    };

    backgroundView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    backgroundView.setOnHoverListener(hoverListener);
```

Comment: post the code where you add the listener

Comment: The methods are called, but I am printing out zeros while pressing the button in onTouch and twos while pressing the button in onHover.

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Comment: No. I was never able to get button events from Samsung while the pen is down. They override the behavior with their own functions.